# How can I reference a control on a tab from another tab?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, tabs

I have a WPF MainWindow with a tab control.
The 1st tab is called Persons and has a GridView bound to a Persons Observable Collection.
I am selecting checkboxes and then click a Next button to go to the next tab which has an almost identical grid of persons bound to SelectedPersons.
But on the first tab's next button, apparently I need to refresh the gridView on the secondtab.

Like datagrid.items.refresh.

I just don't know how to reference it.
Something like this?

```
public override void NextTab()
{
((DataGrid)this.MainTabs[1].Controls["SelectedPersonsGridView"]).items.refresh
}
```

I am a total newbie at WPF and as you can see I have no idea what I am doing but this is basically what I am trying to do.
I just don't know the patterns yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have named the control SelectedPersonsGridView then you don't need to find the control you can just use it's name to reference it.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab1">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="22,36,0,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab2">
                <Grid Name="SelectedPersonsGridView">

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedPersonsGridView.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
}
```